# what is this symbol /\ used while specifying rules in sitemap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, backend, sitemap

I'm trying to make sitemap for my app, and while reading the react-router-sitemap api, I saw this symbol but I was not able to understand the underlined symbol, what is it trying to say.

[image]

Comment: Please read about [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a symbol. The `rules` variable in your example is an array of [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

Since regular expressions are delimited by `/`, the `/` itself must be escaped in a regular expression. In your example, `/\/auth/` means containing `/auth` (the first `/` starts the regular expression and then the `\` escapes the following `/`).